# [GnuTLS Library in a C# project]

Tags: c#, c, gnutls

I am trying to import the GnuTLS library to my C# project and use its APIs. Unfortunately, I cannot find any way on how to do this with the C-based GnuTLS library.

Does anyone know a way on how to use the GnuTLS library in a C# project or even on how to use the Windows build of the GnuTLS library available on their website https://www.gnutls.org/download.html so that I can run it using a C compiler and use the P/Invoke in C# to access the necessary APIs.

(In C#, I tried to import the libraries as reference using MSVS2010 but it says that it is not a valid .NET assembly nor a COM component)
(Also tried the Windows build of this library using a simple C code that calls a function but fails on compilation due to an error "... undefined reference to  ...". I put the header files in MinGW directory as well as the DLL and EXE files).

Comment: Why not use the standard dotnet SSL classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gnutls via P\Invoke. So it's worked on unix platforms.
Example on linux:

```cs
namespace GnuTlsExample
{
   internal static class NativeMethodsLinux {
        internal enum GNUTLS_X509_FMT
        {
            GNUTLS_X509_FMT_DER = 0,
            GNUTLS_X509_FMT_PEM = 1
        }

        [DllImport("libgnutls.so.30")]
        internal static extern int gnutls_x509_crt_list_import(IntPtr certs, ref int cert_max, IntPtr data, GNUTLS_X509_FMT format, uint flags);

        [DllImport("libgnutls.so.30")]
        internal static extern int gnutls_x509_privkey_init(ref IntPtr key);

        [DllImport("libgnutls.so.30")]
        internal static extern int gnutls_x509_privkey_import(IntPtr key,  IntPtr data, GNUTLS_X509_FMT format);

        [DllImport("libgnutls.so.30")]
        internal static extern int gnutls_certificate_set_x509_key(IntPtr cred, IntPtr certs, int max, IntPtr key);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal class gnutls_datum_t
        {
            public IntPtr data = IntPtr.Zero;
            public int size = 0;
        }
  }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var buf = ByteArrayToGnuTlsDatum(File.ReadAllBytes(certificateFilePath));
            var certs = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size);
            var max = 6;
            var tlsCtx = IntPtr.Zero;
            var isServer = 0;           

            var key = IntPtr.Zero;
            var bufKey = MarshalUtils.ByteArrayToGnuTlsDatum(File.ReadAllBytes(keyFilePath));
            var res = NativeMethodsLinux.gnutls_x509_privkey_init(ref key);

            res = NativeMethodsLinux.gnutls_x509_privkey_import(key, bufKey,
                NativeMethodsLinux.GNUTLS_X509_FMT.GNUTLS_X509_FMT_PEM);

            res = NativeMethodsLinux.gnutls_x509_crt_list_import(certs, ref max, buf,
                NativeMethodsLinux.GNUTLS_X509_FMT.GNUTLS_X509_FMT_PEM, 0);

            var cred = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size);
            res = NativeMethodsLinux.gnutls_certificate_set_x509_key(cred, certs, max, key);
        }
        internal static IntPtr ByteArrayToGnuTlsDatum(byte[] bytes)
        {
            var berPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<NativeMethodsLinux.gnutls_datum_t>());
            var valPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(bytes,0,valPtr,bytes.Length);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(new NativeMethodsLinux.gnutls_datum_t
            {
                data = valPtr,
                size = bytes.Length
            }, berPtr, true);
            return berPtr;
        }
     }

}
```